# Purging a scene causes global display objects to be removed from memory

Tags: storyboard, global-variables, coronasdk

I have a problem whereby when I call storyboard.purgeScene(), my global display objects seem to be removed. When I say 'global', they I actually store them in a user-defined storyboard table, to avoid using actual global variables:

My image database is stored in external file toy_database.lua:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard";

    storyboard.globalVars.toys = {
            ball1 = {
                    src = 'img/stock-vector-soccer-ball-trimmed.png',
            }
    }
```

main.lua:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard";

storyboard.globalVars = {};

require "toy_database_toybox";
```

I load some images in my main.lua:

```
storyboard.globalVars.toys["ball1"].imgPtr = display.newImageRect(storyboard.globalVars.toys["ball1"].src, w, h);
```

Then I go to another scene:

```
storyboard.gotoScene("mainFloorScene");
```

where everything is fine, the display objects are accessable. I purge that scene and goto another scene:

```
storyboard.gotoScene( "openBoxScene" )
[in didExitScene()]: storyboard.purgeScene( "mainFloorScene" )
```

Everything is fine here too. Finally I go back to the first scene, purging the current scene on the way:

```
storyboard.gotoScene( "mainFloorScene", "fade", 400 );
[in didExitScene()]: storyboard.purgeScene( "openBoxScene" )
```

Back in the first scene the image objects have been removed. If I comment out the line:

```
storyboard.purgeScene( "openBoxScene" )
```

it works fine, so I have a workaround but I'd like this behaviour explained. I expected a scene purge to only remove display objects local to that scene.

What's going on?

Comment: The iamge is removed, or it only don't appear?

Answer (score 0):

I was using exactly the same method to store my data. I also used purgeScene but my data wasn't removed. I don't want to test this now. I would suggest you to try this on an older build.